# Summarising centrality statistics from several networks in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, graph-theory, igraph

I have data on citations for 25 years (e.g. Author 1 cited Author 2, in Year 2010, 5 times).

```
'data.frame':   7695 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ author_1               : chr  "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
 $ author_2               : chr  "BE" "BE" "BE" "BE" ...
 $ year                   : int  1995 1997 2000 2003 2006 2007 ...
 $ collaborations         : int  1 1 2 4 1 2 3 2 7 2 ...
```

I have to create a weighted graph for every sliding window of 5 years (which will give me 22 graphs) and calculate centrality statistics for all nodes.

**Desired outcome**: dataframe with 5 columns `("window","node","degree","betweenness","closeness")`.

If I do a loop to create a graph for every window (see example below) I will end up with 22 graphs and consequently 22 objects(matrix or dataframe) summarizing centralities for each graph.

```
#a loop creating 22 networks and saving them to the environment with name "window.x"

years<-c(1995:2020)

for (i in 1:22) {
  nam <- paste("window", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam, citations %>%
           filter(year >= years[i] &
                    year <= years[i+4])  %>%
           select(author1, author2, collaborations) %>%
           group_by(author1, author2, ) %>%
           summarize(weight = sum(collaborations),.groups = 'drop'))
}
```

I am looking for a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your full data, but below might be a hint for you to have sliding windows:

```
> embed(1995:2020,5)[,5:1]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999
 [2,] 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000
 [3,] 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001
 [4,] 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002
 [5,] 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003
 [6,] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
 [7,] 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
 [8,] 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
 [9,] 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007
[10,] 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008
[11,] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
[12,] 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
[13,] 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
[14,] 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012
[15,] 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
[16,] 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
[17,] 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
[18,] 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
[19,] 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017
[20,] 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
[21,] 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
[22,] 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
```

Then, you can use `apply` by rows to have your operations with `igraph`.